# Moving files in Windows smb share

Tags: nas, smb

I got two folders mounted via smb. One is G drive and the other is H drive. Both share is from the same nas box.

When I move a folder from H drive to G drive, some folders moves instantly and some will do a move across the network. Say I move a 5GB folder, it will move instantly. Then I try another 5GB folder, it will do a transfer so will go from nas -> my pc -> back to nas again. It's driving me nuts, any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: How is your NAS set up?  If it has multiple physical drives, your problem likely is that sometimes the data that you are moving is on the same drive, and sometimes it is not.

Comment: It has got 4 drives and it is using raid5 with only 1 volume. I sort of fixed it. I mounted the drives in windows using root instead of normal accounts. But the normal accounts do have full rwx access to the files.

Comment: If there is only one volume, where are your two shares coming from?  Are they subdirectories on the same volume?

Comment: Yes, that is right. One of the share is /c/all and the other is /c/home I looked at the file ownership and group. They were different at first and I made them the same but no luck.

Comment: I should clarify this. In windows they are mounted as \\nas\all and \\nas\home but on the linux server the real path is \\nas\c\all and \\nas\c\home\user1. 

I found that if I disconnect the share and mount it as \\nas\c using root account then the files doesn't move across the network. But using normal accounts, some files will move across the network and some doesn't.

Comment: This is ridiculous, I just found my answer. http://www.readynas.com/kb/faq/share/how_can_i_move_files_from_share_to_share_on_the_readynas_without_going_over_the_network

I got so much files that I need moving around.

Comment: The reason that it takes time to move the files is that Windows does not know that all and home are on the same physical drive when you have them mounted separately.  Therefore, it has to read them off of one and write them to the other.  However, when you are mounting /c/, Windows can do a "proper" move because it knows that they are both on the same drive.  The difference is what you are mounting, not who you are doing it as.